# Automated Video creation API

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am looking for a framework or some sort of API that allows for an automated creation of a video based on a template.

For example: A user uploads a short video of himself. The video gets processed: a banner is put over the video and an end title and music is applied to the video based on a predefined template. The finished video is rendered out and available for download.

I have been looking for different approaches and found out that [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) allows for some of the functionality described. Unfortunately it is very finicky as frame rate and resolution always need to match to successfully compile (Which is impossible if the video is uploaded by a user). Also it only allows for one action at a time, which is very unpractical.

Additional I have found [moviemasher.js](http://www.moviemasher.com/), which looked promising, but unfortunately I was not able to get it to work at all.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: *it is very finicky as frame rate and resolution always need to match to successfully compile*
In that case, normalize the video resolution and framerate before mixing the overlay and other content. I used that approach with success in the past.

Comment: I know of software that can do this using its API. See my profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg to resize the template and then mix it with your video to produce the result you want.
with ffmpeg you can do "almost" anything comes to your mind to media files/streams.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have invested a lot of time in ffmpeg and yes I see what you mean, but it is just not something I want to get back to as it is super finicky.